# Issue in joining 2 datasets

Tags: sql, join

I have two datasets like below:

1:

```
+---------------------------+
|  Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3  |
+---------------------------+
| 1 | abc | 0  | 01/01/2010 |
| 2 | def | 10 | 10/10/2011 |
+---------------------------+
```

2:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|    Id   |   Col4 |    Col5 |      Col6    |
+-------------------------------------------+
|    1    |    abc |    0    |   01/01/2010 |
|    5    |    xyz |    12   |    5/6/2013  |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to combine both these into a single dataset which shows something like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  ID  |   Col1  |    Col2  |   Col3      | Col4  |  Col5 |  Col6      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1  |    abc  |    0     |  01/01/2010 |  abc  |   0   | 01/01/2010 |
|   2  |    def  |    10    |  10/10/2011 |  null | null  | null       |
|   5  |    null |   null   |  null       |  xyz  |   12  | 5/6/2013   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The issue is not all ids in dataset 1 are in dataset 2 and vice versa. What i need as all data from datasets1 and 2 and only the common from 1 and 2 with 2 transposed with 1 as shown above. I have used pipe as a separator.

An inputs are highly appreciated. i tried everything like full outer join, inner join , CTE etc - nothing is working.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1 (ID INT, Col1 VARCHAR(100), Col2 INT, Col3 DATETIME)

CREATE TABLE #TEMP2 (ID INT, Col4 VARCHAR(100), Col5 INT, Col6 DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #TEMP1 VALUES (1,'abc',0,'1/1/2010')

INSERT INTO #TEMP1 VALUES (1,'def',0,'1/1/2010')

INSERT INTO #TEMP2 VALUES (1,'abc',0,'1/1/2010')

INSERT INTO #TEMP2 VALUES (1,'def',0,'1/1/2010')

SELECT DISTINCT A.ID,A.Col1,A.Col2,A.Col3,B.Col4,B.Col5,B.Col6
FROM #TEMP1 A
FULL OUTER JOIN #TEMP2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Thanks.

Comment: Full outer join is probably the way to go, why did it not work?

Comment: there are some rows which are exactly identical like the one where id = 1 - there is am getting 2 rows instead of 1.

Comment: Given your sample data that is not possible. Create an sqlfiddle or provide create table statements and some insert statements and show us what you did try

Comment: @lennart: for some reason i could not include the code in comment - hence i updated my initial post.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Let's simplify and use only id and col1, col4. Given your sample data there are 4 different combinations (1,abc,abc),(1,abc,def),(1,def,abc),(1,def,def). Which ones do you want in the result?

Comment: i need only 2 rows as its having only 2 rows in common.                                                                                                        1     abc   0      1/1/2010                                                                                                        1 abc 0 1/1/2010

Answer (score 0):

Try using below SQL :

```html
select t1.Id , Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , Col4 , Col5 , Col6
from temp1 t1 left join temp2 t2
on t1.Id=t2.Id
union
select t2.Id , Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , Col4 , Col5 , Col6
from temp1 t1 right join temp2 t2
on t1.Id=t2.Id
```

Also, i tried on fiddle for you :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d60a1e/5

Comment: Kumaraswamy - Let me know if you find any issue with this answer.

Comment: the same duplicate rows keeps popping up again.

Comment: How Come, please refer sqlfiddle  link in my answer, it is giving same answer as you are exepcting.

Comment: for some reason the sqlfiddle link is not opening in my work computer. can you please try using the reference script i have used in the initial post?

Comment: the rows have to be exactly identical - there are instances in my datasets where 2 rows are exactly identical and the result set is having 4 rows, 3 identical rows in each dataset is yielding 9 rows in the combined set

Comment: as i said before - the rows have to be exactly identical - please use the script i have used in the main post.

Comment: Because, There are 4 identical combination that's why it is dipslaying 4 rows in your example. what is your expectation here ?

Comment: i need only 2 rows no more

Comment: It will not possible, if you apply join for only Id column. for this particular output you need to add 2nd condition also. But it will change your whole output. SELECT DISTINCT A.ID,A.Col1,A.Col2,A.Col3,B.Col4,B.Col5,B.Col6
FROM TEMP1 A full outer join TEMP2 B ON A.ID = B.ID and A.Col1=B.Col4

Comment: i cannot as i have other rows in the dataset which do not match on the second condition. i have some rows which are exactly identical in both the datasets , which are unique in each dataset as well. my output should be the unique rows from each dataset and the matching rows from both the datasets (there are some identical ones and some which have only matching ids.)

Comment: Then, you need to write two scripts to retrieve your results then you need to distinct them out using union or temporary table(select distinct).